# How to pass an entire query from Android to a PHP file using $_POST and Volley?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-volley

im working in a proyect with android and MySQL databases, and i need to pass the entire query from Android to the PHP file.

Here is the .php:

```html
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "myuser", "mypass", "mydatabase");

$query =$_POST["query"];
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $query);
$result = mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 
 {
  array_push($response,
                array('id'=>$row[0],
               'name'=>$row[1],
               'email'=>$row[2]));
 }

mysqli_close($enlace);

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$response));



?>
```

And this is the java class at Android:

```js
public class ParamQuery extends StringRequest {

    private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public ParamQuery(String query,Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("query", query);

    }
}
```

And this how i call it:

```js
public void send_custom_request()
    {
        final String myquery = "SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE id=3";

        Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                showJSON(response);

            }
        };

        ParamQuery paramQuery = new ParamQuery(myquery,responseListener);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        queue.add(paramQuery);
    }
}
```

But im having problems with php file, aparently i cant declare "$result" in that way.

Can someone give me a hand?
thanks

Comment: Why not just try echo json_encode($response);

Comment: Is it normal to post queries to a php page from android apps? It seems like a security vulnerability.

Comment: @jeff im pretty sure that is not the problem, besides i have to encode it that way for external reasons.

Comment: @Terminus im ok with that, besides its a test for a more complicated work :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add this to your custom request class parmQuery

```
@Override protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError { return params; }
```